# Checking if the input is a number or something else

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to check if a string in a variable has numbers inside of it or not.

This is the code I use to go over the variable:

```
function checkIfOk(pass){
    for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
        if(/[0-9]/.test(pass)){
            console.log("Number: "+pass[i]);
        }else{
            console.log("Letter: "+pass[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is invoked by this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".PWD1").on("keypress keyup", function() {
        var pass = $(this).val();
        $("#check").text(checkIfOk(pass));
    });
});
```

So it reads a string from a password field and then goes over every element in that string with a for loop. It will check with the IF statement, if the pass[i] is a number from 0-9, if it is it will print to console Number: x.

But for some reason, the else statement is working only when I have no numbers in my string, when a number is inserted, the for loop will accept all elements as numbers and disregard my else statement.
Why is that?

Comment: Your regular expression tests the entire string every time, not just the single character you want to be looking at.

Comment: How silly of me, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
function checkIfOk(pass){
    var status = "";
 for (var i=0; i<pass.length; i++) {
    status = isNan(pass[i]);
    if(status==false){
        console.log("Number: "+pass[i]);
    }else{
        console.log("Letter: "+pass[i]);
    }
 }
}
```